# How to filter out a particular keyword(part/Substring) which is unique from a map key?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a Map<String,String>

```
{
  BusDetails0.BusDetail.DriverID=1,
  BusDetails0.BusDetail.DriverSubID=2,
  BusDetails1.BusDetail.DriverID=1,
  BusDetails1.BusDetail.DriverSubID=2
}
```

from this map is it possible to extract keys in a list of Strings {"BusDetails0","BusDetails1"}?

please help thanks

Comment: In general you can't query a map based on a partial key so you'd have to iterate over all the entries and compare the keys one by one. However, if you'd be using a `SortedMap` (`TreeMap` being one of the most common implementations) you could implement some "starts with" logic using `subMap(fromKey, toKey)`, e.g. `subMap("BusDetails0", "BusDetails0\uFFFF")` to get all entries where the key starts with "BusDetails0" (the end key would need to just be outside the intended range that's why I added `"\uFFFF"` instead of using "BusDetails1" as the "to key").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a set of keys:

```
map.keySet()
```

In your case, if I understand correctly, you want to get a list of transformed keys (all characters before the first dot symbol)

```
List<String> list = map.keySet().stream().map(s -> s.split("\\.")[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: List<String> list = outputMap.keySet().stream().map(s -> s.split("\\.")[0]).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()); I have used this , its getting me the unique values. thank you